# drawable qualifiers, Bitmaps aren't changed correctly after screen rotation on HTC with Android 4+

Tags: android, rotation, drawable, htc-android

I have a problem with drawables on HTC Sensation and HTC One S.

I have graphics in drawable-nodpi folder:

```
icon_l.png
icon_m.png
```

In drawable-hdpi folder I have file icon.xml with code:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_l" />
```

In drawable-land-hdpi folder I have file icon.xml with code:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_m" />
```

In drawable folder I have selector file button.xml with code:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/icon_pressed" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon" />
</selector>
```

In layout I have:

```
<ImageButton android:src="@drawable/button"/>
```

Everything works ok, on almost all phones and tablets: graphics on landscape are smaller and when I back to portrait graphics are again bigger;

but not on HTC sensation and HTC one S: graphics on this phones are loaded randomly when I rotate phone.

I suppose that may be any cache?
I tried setContentView to other layout and again reloaded correct layout, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to duplicate this behavior on a Sensation running stock ICS Android. Only workaround I found so far was to put an extra copy of button.xml in each HDPI folder.

Comment: Thank You Lance, I finally changed design in my project, but I just have tested Your solution and works fine.